# Provide header names to autocomplete suggestions columns

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces autocomplete componant for multiple columns.

I am able to display multiple columns result, but I want a header name for each column. 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf
As you can see in this demo there are two columns in auto suggestions as name and image,

I want to provide header name to name and image , means it will looks like in this way

```
Player_Name    Picture    (Header names for columns)

  Messi         (its image)
```

I tried to give  header names using in this way but didn't worked

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer2}" id="customPojo" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completePlayer}"  
                        var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="player" forceSelection="true">  
                <p:column>  
                  <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Player Image" />
            </f:facet> 

                   <p:graphicImage value="/images/barca/#{p.photo}" width="40" height="50"/>  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Player Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{#{p.name}}" />

                </p:column>  
            </p:autoComplete>
```

> and also I want to display 5 columns as a suggestion like as in this
>   demo there are only 2 columns  as a suggestion but I have 5 columns as
>   a suggestions so it displays all columns but it takes by default
>   horizontal slider . but i don't want a slider over there , atleast 5
>   columns should be displayed without any slider.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to set headers in autocomplete component

[Issue 3567:    Column header for autocomplete columns](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3567)

About the scroll you should look with your firebug on what `id` got your auto complete opened dialog and apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to it

in the showcase for example it should be something like

```
 #form:customPojo_panel table{
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

might need to add some other css stuff like `display: inline-block` or assign `min-width`

Comment: Provide header names to autocomplete suggestions columns

no , I tried it, but didn't worked